# Vue app with node, express and xampp - right project structure

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, mysqli, xampp

I want to create CRUD application using technologies like:
- Vue.js
- Node & Express
- mysqli (xampp)

What is the best way to make project structure (directory and files tree)?
If dividing two folders - front with Vue files and server with others is a correct practice? Or maybe the whole app should base on the one of that, for example vue and all other files/folders should take place inside of vue folder? I know that it is a lot of right ways, but what which of that are the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting into front end and backend is usually the first step to take for me, then as development continues you can refactor as needed. I'd take some time to review github and find projects that are well setup, for example:

https://github.com/mozilla-iot/gateway